# How to use Igr Data grid in Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, datagrid, grid, infragistics

I am new to Next js and currently I'm trying to use igr data grid in my application.
When I am trying to use igr data grid in react but I'm getting error **"ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined"**

How it can be done?

My code:

```
    import { IgrDataGrid } from "igniteui-react-grids";
    import { IgrTextColumn } from "igniteui-react-grids";
    
    const details = [
      {
        Name: "Jack",
        Company : "Google",
      },
      {
        Name: "Jack",
        Company : "Google",
      },
      {
        Name: "Jack",
        Company : "Google",
      },
      {
        Name: "Jack",
        Company : "Google",
      },
      {
        Name: "Jack",
        Company : "Google",
      },
      {
        Name: "Jack",
        Company : "Google",
      },
    ];
    
    const table = () => {
      return (
          <h1>USER DETAILS</h1>
          <div>
            <div className="container">
              {
                <IgrDataGrid dataSource={details}>
                  <IgrTextColumn field="Name" horizontalAlignment="center" />
                  <IgrTextColumn field="Company" horizontalAlignment="center" />
                </IgrDataGrid>
              }
            </div>
          </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out below code.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { IgrDataGrid, IgrTextColumn } from 'igniteui-react-grids';

const details = [
  {
    Name: 'Jack',
    Company: 'Google',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Jack',
    Company: 'Google',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Jack',
    Company: 'Google',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Jack',
    Company: 'Google',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Jack',
    Company: 'Google',
  },
  {
    Name: 'Jack',
    Company: 'Google',
  },
];

const Table = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const IgrDataGridScript = document.createElement('script');
    IgrDataGridScript.src = 'https://cdn.infragistics.com/igniteui/2021.1/latest/js/infragistics.core.js';
    document.body.appendChild(IgrDataGridScript);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>USER DETAILS</h1>
      <div className="container">
        <IgrDataGrid dataSource={details}>
          <IgrTextColumn field="Name" horizontalAlignment="center" />
          <IgrTextColumn field="Company" horizontalAlignment="center" />
        </IgrDataGrid>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: It's not working, giving the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic NextJS import to disable SSR

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DynamicIgniteGrid = dynamic(
  () => import("../components/grid"),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
)
```